# Using Ajax to access HTML dropdown value and then call PHP Function

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

Admittedly I am completely clueless when it comes to Ajax, but it appears the best way to accomplish my task.  After going through several tutorials, I have a basic understanding, but remain lost in regards to my problem.  Essentially I am attempting to capture the value of an HTML dropdown menu and call a shopping cart function with the user selected row value.  Each row value corresponds to a product in a php arrray.

Function appearing in my header file (Note: The commented out portion is a failed attempt using the onreadystatechange):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function productchange(data){

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  //xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  //{
  //if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  // {
  //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= data;
  //  }
  //}

  var URL = "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themeX/order.php" + "?rownum=" + data;

  xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,false);
  xmlhttp.send(); 

}
//-->
</script>
```

HTML Table: (Once again the div tags are a failed attempt using innerHTML.  I was able to get the value on the screen, but still not able to capture it with $_GET to use in my function call)

```
<TR>
   <TD>
      <select id="productcategory1" name="productcategory1" onchange="productchange(this.value)">
    <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Product # 1 - $1.99</option>
    <option value="2">Product # 2 - $1.99</option>
    <option value="3">Product # 3 - $9.99</option>
    <option value="4">Product # 4 - $9.99</option>
  </select>
  </TD>
  <TD>    
  <div id="test">
  </div>
  <?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($products[$rownum]["Product"], $products[$rownum]["Price"]); ?>
  </TD>
  </TR>
```

Order.php:

```
<?php
global var $rownum;
$rownum = $_GET['rownum'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`order.php` doesn't do anything, really, and echoes no response back to the client. What is the AJAX call actually supposed to do? (Remember, a PHP script executes once at the time the initial page is rendered, so the AJAX call is just a completely separate web request that then needs to give back some data that the client will handle in the onreadystatechange function. Try adding an echo to `order.php` and you should see that show up in the div when you uncomment the JS handler.

Comment: My intention in creating the AJAX call was to capture the current row selected by the user of the drop down menu, and use that row to identify an item in my product array.  Subsequently, I call the print_wp_cart_button_for_product function, which when pressed adds the product to the cart.  More or less, I was hoping that order.php could be used to change the value of my php variable $rownum.